# How to remove Skype second instance?

Tags: skype, multiple-instances

how can I remove the second instance of skype?
created the second instance by **skype --secondary** command.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two instances of skype **opened** or **installed**?  If the former, why don't you just close it? If the latter, please describe how you installed each instance.

Comment: can you help me on this too https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356734/fingerprint-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts